# Postgres query on nested array failing to return results

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM post p
 , jsonb_array_elements(p.meta #> '{tags, tag}') d
WHERE  d->>'tag' LIKE '%mytag%';
```

Which isn't returning any results, I have an object in the post table that looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure why this is failing, my understanding was jsonb_array_elements flattens out arrays and by selecting {tags, tag} it would get the tag string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the nested array is `meta #> '{tags}'`, not `meta #> '{tags, tag}'`, so this should work

```sql
select *
from 
    post p,
    jsonb_array_elements(p.meta #> '{tags}') d
where d->>'tag' like '%mytag%';

-- or simpler

select *
from 
    post p,
    jsonb_array_elements(p.meta -> 'tags') d
where d->>'tag' like '%mytag%';
```

Comment: that was it! I and really appreciate the simpler example - much nicer syntax for json selection